# Use of Maximum Entropy in Sentiment Analysis

Tags: sentiment-analysis, entropy

I want to use Maximum Entropy Classifier for doing Sentiment Analysis on Tweets. My knowledge of statistics is very basic. Can you suggest some good tutorial or books on Maximum Entropy Classifier that explains the steps required for implementing one in detail , including selection of features and mathematical calculations involved. I have gone through various materials on net, but haven't found anything that is much helpful in this regard. Thanks in advance

Comment: Be careful: typos have high entropy, too.

Comment: If you just need to use it, there are plenty of better off-the-shelf libraries instead of implementing your own, such as the one in Weka, Mallet, etc. The "Speech and Language Processing" book covers the basics and intuitions, and for the math, you probably want to take a look at the Pattern Recognition and ML book by Bishop or search for some lecture slides on that topic.